# Display records based on data with different time format

Tags: mysql, date, timestamp

I have a column with timestamp in millisecond '1394647007306'
and I have an other column with a list of 'names'
how can I display those names by calling with a date like 'March 12, 2014'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with seconds since 1970 (i.e. Unix timestamps then [FROM_UNIXTIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)) could well be what you want.

```
mysql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1196440219);
        -> '2007-11-30 10:30:19'
mysql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1196440219) + 0;
        -> 20071130103019.000000
mysql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '%Y %D %M %h:%i:%s %x');
        -> '2007 30th November 10:30:59 2007'
```

The value is expressed in the current time zone.

Answer (score 0):

If you time value matches Unix time, use `FROM_UNIXTIME`.

```
mysql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1196440219);
        -> '2007-11-30 10:30:19'
```

More info [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).